# Ask an if an file already exist with errors

Tags: bash

I want to ask for two files. If one of the files doesn't exist ask for another file that does exist and this is how I'm trying to do it. But it doesn't really work, maybe I made it a bit to hard for what it needs to do?

```
echo which two files do you want?
read file1
read file2

touch error1
touch error2

while [ count1 > 0 ]
echo the file doesn't exists give another one
read file1

while [ count2 > 0 ]
echo the file doesn't exist give another one
read file2

$file1 2> error1
$file2 2> error2

count1=wc<error1
count2=wc<error2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want to repeatedly ask for a filename until you get one that exists.  I'd write a function for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_existing_file() {
    read -r -p "Filename: " f
    until test -e "$f"
    do
        read -r -p "$f not found; new filename: " f
    done
    echo "$f"
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
file1=$(get_existing_file)
file2=$(get_existing_file)
```

Comment: `IFS= read -r -p ...` so that you accept filenames with backslashes and leading/trailing spaces :)

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to have your code checked by shellcheck.net or something comparable before submitting it to stackoverflow. The code that you have submitted does not make sense, and although Toby's code might be the solution, it may be worthwhile to go through your code.

```
echo which two files u want? read file1 read file2
```

This echoes:

```
which two files u want? read file1 read file2
```

It does not read variables. If you wanted to do that, you should have done:

```
echo "which two files u want?"
read file1 
read file2
```

Whether it is a good idea to touch the error files is a matter of choice; In general, I would not do it.

```
while [ count1 > 0 ]
echo the file doesn't exists give another one
read file1
```

This is not correct bash. There are two things that are just syntax errors and that should have been solved by yourself.

A while loop in bash uses `do` - `done` to mark the beginning and end of the block in the while-loop. They are not present here. A simple check on shellcheck.net would have revealed

```
SC1073: Couldn't parse this while loop.
```

The next problem is the one with a quote. If you open a (single) quote, you must close it. The best way here would be to put double quotes around them. So, not even looking at the semantics, it would be:

```
while [ count1 > 0 ] ; do
    echo "the file doesn't exists give another one"
    read file1
done
```

Then there is the question of your condition in the while-loop. The string `count1` is greater then `0`. So the while-loop will execute forever asking you yet another file. If you meant to use a variable `count1`, in bash you would need to dereference it with a `$`-sign, as in

```
while [ $count1 > 0 ] ; do
```

But you might want to set that variable somewhere. (I'm not getting into the discussion about quoting here). Here, > does not test numerical-greater-than; you will want numeric comparison, `-gt`.

If I understood the functionality that you need correctly, you want to know if the `file1` is an existing file. So what you actually want is

```
while [ ! -f "$file1" ] ; do
```

(same for your `file2`-block)
Note that I put quotes around the `$file1`. This is because the filename might contain spaces. So that would make:

```
"$file1" 2> error1
"$file2" 2> error2
```

Below, you are setting the `count1` and `count2` variables. Did you mean to use them in your loop? or are you just re-using their names here?

```
count1=wc<error1
count2=wc<error2
```

`wc` also takes a filename argument, so you do not need to redirect stdin. However, you must use the syntax from bash to use the output from `wc`. So that would be:

```
count1=$(wc error1)
```

I've tried to be as polite and educational as possible, but please, at least produce some serious effort at shell programming and not some messy attempt at pseudo-code.

Comment: `while [ $count1 > 0 ] ; do` is also not correct, it should be `while [ "$count1" -gt 0 ] ; do` or `while (( count1 > 0 )); do`

Comment: `>` tests if strings are greater, so it is correctish. Added the remark of using `-gt` in the reply, because your remark is of course more than valid.

Comment: `>` is a redirection, there.  You might be thinking of `[[`..`]]` tests, in which `>` is a binary operator.

Comment: hm. For someone who is criticizing someone else's code, I seem to make quite a few error of my own. Corrected it in the answer.